# Undefined variable admob in PhoneGap AdMob plugin

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova, jquery-mobile

It's difficult for me to explain my problem because my english is not good, hope you would understand.

This is my first try to make a mobile game, all done and I want to show ads by AdMob. I have tried some PhoneGap AdMob plugins such as admob-phonegap , cordova-admob-pro , etc,.. but all of them give "undefined" error on variable named "admob" (or "AdMob") .

There are the step I try with PhoneGap:

1. Install NodeJS.
2. Install Cordova.
3. Install PhoneGap.
4. Create app by command: **phonegap test_app**
5. **cd test_app** and **phonegap platform add ios**
6. Add plugin for my test_app by command: **phonegap plugin add [plugin_name]** (also try with **cordova plugin add [plugin_name]**)
7. Write some html to test the AdMob plugin:

   document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){

   try{
   if(admob){alert("OK!");}
   }catch(e){alert(e);}

   },false);

**8. Start test_app on my computer by command: phonegap serve.**

9. Install PhoneGap Developer (http://app.phonegap.com/) App for my iPhone and connect with my computer, all work fine expect the "admob" variable is not defined !

I am using Windows 8 and there are not software be installed before (include Java,...)

Thank you for understanding and helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using Cordova or PhoneGap command line tool locally, you need install Java and Android SDK first.

If you don't want to install Android SDK locally, you can use PhoneGap Build service, which is a commercial cloud build service offered by Adobe. Or else you can try Intel XDK, which is a IDE and another could build service.

To use AdMob you have to build it into APP and install APP to device or simulator. As it will pack plugin which contains native code.

Running PhoneGap serve and use browser to visit it, only load html5 and JavaScript code, it won't work.

Comment: Yes, if I use browser to visit it would load html5 and js only, I use the app at http://app.phonegap.com to load. Please take a look at my link. Thank you :)

Comment: PhoneGap Developer APP does not contain the admob plugin (I mean, the native code), so it cannot find the plugin. You have to build an APP yourself with the admob plugin in it.

Comment: Thanx for this post & answer, I was so much stuck because i was trying it on browser and it was not working.